# How to get unsigned equivalent of an integral type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to get an unsigned equivalent (same size) of a signed integral type in C++? I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
template<typename T>
struct get_unsigned { };

template<>
struct get_unsigned<int> {
    typedef unsigned int type;
};

...

template<typename T>
void myfunc(T val) {
    get_unsigned<T>::type u = std::abs(val);
    ...
}
```

I'm looking for an existing solution in the standard library or Boost and prefer not to roll my own unless it's a handful of lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost.TypeTraits has [`make_unsigned`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/make_unsigned.html):

> type: If T is a unsigned integer type then the same type as T, if T is an signed integer type then the corresponding unsigned type. Otherwise if T is an enumerated or character type (char or wchar_t) then an unsigned integer type with the same width as T.
>
> If T has any cv-qualifiers then these are also present on the result type.

[The source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/type_traits/make_unsigned.hpp) is much more than a handful of lines.

Comment: This was added to the stdlib in C++11 as, predictably, `std::make_unsigned`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/make_unsigned/

Answer (score 2):

As commented by underscore_d on "James McNellis" answer, one can now use standard `std::make_unsigned` function: https://cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/make_unsigned.

Nice when you don't want to use boost for this.